# Find a polynomial of the specified degree that satisfies the given conditions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Find a polynomial of the specified degree that satisfies the given
>   conditions.
>   Degree $4$; zeros $-1$, $0$, $3$, $1/3$ ; coefficient of $x^3$ is $7$

My answer is...
$$
P(x)=3x^4 - 7x^3 - 7x^2 + 3x.
$$
When I entered this answer into the software (MindTap) for my class it was marked incorrect. mymathportal.com and wolframalpha.com both agree with my answer.

Is there another format that could be also correct or something I am missing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Zeros: -1, 0, 3, 1/3

Comment: Your coeffecient for $x^3$ is $-7$, requested seems to be $7$.

Comment: In your answer, the coefficient of $x^3$ is $-7$, not $7$.

Comment: Roots are correct. Multiply it by -1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Since
>   $\ds{\braces{\color{#f00}{-1},\color{#f00}{0},\color{#f00}{3},\color{#f00}{{1 \over 3}}}}$ are the *polynomial roots*, the polynomial we are looking for is *proportional to*

\begin{align}
\bracks{x - \color{#f00}{\pars{-1}}}\pars{x - \color{#f00}{0}}
\pars{x - \color{#f00}{3}}\pars{x - \color{#f00}{{1 \over 3}}} =
x^{4} - {7 \over 3}\,x^{3} - {7 \over 3}\,x^{2} + x
\end{align}
In order to 'adjust' the $\ds{x^{3}\!}$-coefficient, multiply it by
$\ds{-3 \implies \bbox[8px,#efe,border:0.1em groove navy]{-3x^{4} + \color{#f00}{7}x^{3} + 7x^{2} - 3x}}$

Answer (score -1):

The answer was found in the comments to be
$$P(x)=-3x^4+7x^3+7x^2-3x$$

Comment: You can check the $\LaTeX$ source underlying the MathJax formatting of the Question to get an idea how to post math expressions,  Also have a look at the [introductory note](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).